# print a page scope dynamically updated from http rfequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to print a html page. I'm using angular.js. I have a http request to get data. I have problem that, the print area was not updated with first http request:

```
http.post(url,data).then(function(result) {
    $scope.data = result.data; 
    print($("#printarea").html());
});
```

Anybody know why this is happening? How can I call my print function after DOM updated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use $scope.$apply() before print as following :

```
http.post(url,data).then(function(result)
{
   $scope.data=result.data;
   $scope.$apply(); 
   print($("#printarea").html());
});
```

Comment: thank you for replay. but that throws an error [$rootScope:inporg] not work for me

Comment: any another solution?

Comment: you can use timeout something around 2-3 second.

Comment: can you post an example here?

Comment: sure. please refer this link. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106899/discussion-between-jainish-jariwala-and-ajith).

Comment: that was also failed :(